# MySQL CREATE FUNCTION with email parameter with IF SELECT as return

Tags: mysql

I receive the following error when using the below function and can not figure out how to fix it.

Error:

```
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ';
  RETURN IF(result IS NOT NULL, result, '0');
  END' at line 8
```

Function:

```
delimiter $$
CREATE FUNCTION expirations(email VARCHAR(255))
RETURNS VARCHAR(255)
READS SQL DATA
BEGIN
    DECLARE result VARCHAR(255);
    SET result = NULL;
    IF (LENGTH(verify_email) > 8) THEN SELECT expiration_date INTO result FROM paypal WHERE payer_email = email;
    ENDIF;
    RETURN IF(result IS NOT NULL, result, '0');
END$$
delimiter ;
```

Email would be read in as a varchar or text such as "user@domain.com"

expiration_date is a of type TIMESTAMP

payer_email is of type VARCHAR(255)

I've also tried the following function with a different error being shown.

Error:

```
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that      corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ';
    READS SQL DATA
    BEGIN
        DECLARE result TIMESTAMP;
        SET res' at line 2
```

Function:

```
delimiter $$
CREATE FUNCTION expirations(email VARCHAR(255))
RETURNS TIMESTAMP;
READS SQL DATA
BEGIN
    DECLARE result TIMESTAMP;
    SET result = NULL;
    IF (LENGTH(verify_email) > 8) THEN SELECT expiration_date INTO result FROM paypal WHERE payer_email = email;
    ENDIF;
    RETURN IF(result IS NOT NULL, result, '0');
END$$
delimiter ;
```

I want to use either of these functions so that an application can just pass in expiration(email); and get a result if the email is of length 9 or greater or otherwise receive nothing.

UPDATE:

Thank you KAILLINGER. Spent 2 hours working on this, and it was a typo! :(

Correct answer for completeness:

```
delimiter $$
CREATE FUNCTION expirations(email VARCHAR(255))
RETURNS VARCHAR(200)
READS SQL DATA
BEGIN
    DECLARE result VARCHAR(200);
    SET result = NULL;
    IF (LENGTH(email) > 8) THEN SELECT expiration_date INTO result FROM paypal WHERE payer_email = email;
    END IF;
    RETURN IF(result IS NOT NULL, result, '0');
END$$
delimiter ;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `ENDIF;` is not good, it should be `END IF;` :)